# end kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init! exitcode = 0x00007f00

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2myJf.jpg)

I cannot access terminal and recovery mode is also not working. Please, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try allocating more processor to your Virtual Machine by going to settings ->System ->Processor and set processor to more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

When init process is terminated for some reasons, the linux force kernel panic with below message
kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init! exitcode = 0x00007f00

Please follow below steps to narrow down kernel panic.

1. If code is changed, you had better review code change from userspace code rather kernel space code.
2. Make sure to install linux machine in correct way if this kernel panic
3. Check the file system is properly mounted(ex: root)

BR,
Guillermo Austin Kim

Answer (score 0):

Burn the .iso file of the linux distros you want to boot with using a flash drive using rufus (in windows pc) then power your pc and press ESC then F9 then boot from the USB drive, then press F6 to access other options, then check in from the drop line "acpi=off", "noapic", "nolapic", "edd=on", "nodmraid", "nomodeset", press ESC and click on install or try your distros and enjoy.... 
Problem solved

Check it out and share your experience